# Spring SimpleJdbcInsert fails with 'INSERT has more target columns than expressions'

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc

I am using a SimpleJdbcInsert to insert rows into a PostgreSQL database.  However, I get an  the following error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INSERT has more
> target columns than expressions.
> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT
> INTO product (product_id,product_name,product_code,in_
> stock,product_category) VALUES(?)]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0];
> ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
> transaction block; nested exception is
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is
> aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

The number columns is exactly the same as the number of values I am trying to insert when I print out the MapSqlParameterSource object shown below:

```
        Parameters Names :: 
        [
        product_id,
        product_name, 
        product_code, 
        in_ stock, 
        product_category
      ]

       Parameters Values :: [{
       product_id=1518, 
       product_name=Sofa, 
       product_code=150,  
       in_stock=true, 
       product_category=null, 
     }]
```

The product_id is the primary key and it is not null. Could the problem be because I am not using an auto-generated primary key?  I still do not understand why that would be a problem.

The columns shown in the error message are precisely the same as the columns in the parameter list I'm printing. The values also tally with the number of columns as well, so I'm really baffled why PostgreSQL is giving this error. Please help!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As the exception shows, your application tried to execute an insert with five columns and only one parameter placeholder in the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a lot and some content I cannot expose.  I rewrote the code with a  different solution and got it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a different solution to using Spring JDBC.